# Deleted /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf on Ubunutu 18.04 Bionic Beaver

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I am fairly new to Ubuntu, so sorry in advance for noobishness of all this...
I recently got a new Nvidia GPU wanted to install it in my system. It wasn't working at all. Tried all the documentation online and nothing was working...I found a post where they said to:

> sudo rm -rf /etc/X11/xorg.config

Sadly that file isn't located there in 18.04. I asked one of my friends who told me that it was no had a different path and should try:

> sudo rm -rf /usr/share/X11/xorg.config

(I wanted to get rid of it since all my mishaps were screwing with it...)

I thought it would automatically generate a new one on restart but I can't even boot it now. I am perfectly fine with nuking from the BIOS but I sadly don't know how to either nuke my system or find some magical hack of fixing the problem.

Comment: You should be able to boot off a live disk, chroot into your dead install, and reinstall the relevant package(s). Also this is more of an askubuntu.com question than a stackoverflow question.

Comment: Sorry will do in the future...sorry for the late response don't have a good excuse other than life...